# TSQL to know if database mirroring is setup for both PRimary and secondary server

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, database-mirroring

I have Database mirroring setup between two SQl 2005 servers (no witness).
Using Tsql, I want to find if there is a user database on both primary and mirror server.
I can use the following on mirror:

```
select * from sys.databases where state <>1 and database_id>4
```

What should i use for Primary server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [dmvs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366276(SQL.90).aspx) associated with database mirroring

For example, [sys.database_mirroring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178655(SQL.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
Kindly find Data using Following Query :-
```

**SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) AS Database_Name,

mirroring_state_desc,

mirroring_role_desc,

mirroring_safety_level_desc,

mirroring_partner_name,

mirroring_witness_name,

mirroring_witness_state_desc,

mirroring_failover_lsn

FROM sys.database_mirroring

WHERE mirroring_state IS NOT NULL;**